# how to get before date Rates using sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select rateperkg from K_FS_FeedMrpDetails where date = getdate()-1
```

I want to display rateperkg column before date values

Comment: I think I'll delete my answer. Your question is way too abstract and incomplete. Please, state what exactly it is that you need and what is the data type of your `date` column to avoid getting so many similar answers. It'll make it clearer for other people looking for similar solutions

Answer (score 1):

Try this

get Yesterday

```
select rateperkg from K_FS_FeedMrpDetails where date = DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())
```

see this link for more details.

I think this will helps you

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/29/sql-server-few-useful-datetime-functions-to-find-specific-dates/

Comment: Only last date means? you mean previous date of todays date?

Comment: yes..getdate() with minutes,sec..but my "date" column with 0 minits,0 sec ..so

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DATEADD()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function and cast it to Date to remove time part like below

```
SELECT rateperkg 
FROM   k_fs_feedmrpdetails 
WHERE  date = Cast(Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DATE);
```

Comment: In sql 2008, it's working fine, check this demo link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64172/1

Answer (score 1):

**This code will set time to zero.**

```
declare @DaVal as datetime

--111 will return yyyy/MM/dd
--101 will return MM//dd/yyyy
set @DaVal = convert(datetime, convert(varchar(25), DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()), 111)) 

select rateperkg from K_FS_FeedMrpDetails where date = @DaVal
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date column stores date and time then use the below condition

```
where date >=convert(date,getdate()-1)
and date < getdate()
```

else

```
where date = convert(date,getdate()-1)
```